# Rails 4 - associations between controllers, id not getting passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have two controllers categories and products. Products belongs to categories but I'm having trouble setting up the relationship.

In category.rb

```
has_many :products
```

In product.rb

```
belongs_to :category

validates :category_id, :presence => true
validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

When I try to create a new product, the record does not save because category_id is blank. My product form looks like so:

```
<%= form_for @product, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field('category_id', :value => params[:category_id]) %>

<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :category, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <% @cat = Category.all %>
    <%= select_tag 'category', options_from_collection_for_select(@cat, 'id', 'name') %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :price, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :price, :class => 'text_field' %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_area :description, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 10, :cols => 120 %>
    <%= tinymce %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
  products_path, :class => 'btn' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and in the products controller I have:

```
  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @category = @product.category
  end
```

I've tried looking through other questions on SO but haven't had any luck finding the correct way to pass the category id to products. 
I hope I've been clear enough and I'm happy to provide any extra information that may be needed.

**EDIT**

I've made the following changes to the products controller as suggested by I not get the error: Cannot find Category without an ID

```
before_filter :set_category, only: [:create]

  def set_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  end

  def create
    @product = @category.products.new(product_params)

    #....
  end
```

I'm using nested routes like so:

```
  resources :categories do 
    resources :products
  end
```

Comment: @product.category is nil in your last snippet. You just initialized a new Product - it doesn't know anything of any categories yet!

Comment: Note that `validates :category_id, :presence => true` only validates that there's something non blank in `category_id`, so any integer would work (even if there's no category with that ID). Maybe you want to use `validates :category, :presence => true` ?

Comment: @tight Thanks, I'll try that in a minute or two but I still need to pass a category id through somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set product's category in `create` action:

```
def create
  @product = @category.products.new(product_params)
  # ...
end
```

in `new` action, you should just have

```
def create
  @product = Product.new
end
```

Of course, you need to set `@category` (`@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])`) instance variable before (in `before_filter`, for example).

You should also remove this hidden field from view and remove `category_id` from allowed params if you don't want users to set `category_id` manually and set `form_for` arguments properly, since you're using nested resources:

```
form_for [@category, @product]
```

Comment: Is using a before_filter better practice than setting @category in the line above where product is being set?

Comment: @SoSimple in this case, probably yes, because you're gonna need this variable also in other actions.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Also, sorry if I'm being a nuisance but I'm having trouble setting @category. The product hasn't been created yet so I can't find a category by id or even name.

Comment: @SoSimple If you use nested routes (which you should, it seems), you have `params[:category_id]` through which you can easily find your `Category`.

Comment: Maybe I'm making a silly mistake somewhere because I get 'Couldn't find Category without an ID' when I try to create a new product. I've edited my question to show how I've added your suggestions.

Comment: @SoSimple how does your path look like?

Comment: @SoSimple yes, when you get the error. BTW, `set_category` should be private method in your controller.

Comment: Your path should be `/categories/:id/products`. You should have `[@category, @product]` in your `form_for`.

Comment: Form now has <%= form_for [@category, @product], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %> and I refreshed the page, and restarted the server but still getting 'Couldn't find Category without an ID' and the path is still /products even though I changed the route in the create action from @product to category_product_path

Comment: @SoSimple are you sure you set `@category` variable in `new` action? Plus, of course, your path to new product should be `/categories/:id/products/new`.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that when I changed my routes and nested products within categories I didn't delete the old products route so there was a lot of conflicting paths. I'm correcting everything and hopefully that will be problem solved!

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine now. Thanks so much for your help!